# variance parameters

Tags: distributions, sampling

Suppose we are told that a population distribution of a random variable X is normal with parameters μ = 1 and σ2 = 9. Simple random samples of sample size n=9 are taken and the
sample means Xn=9 are obtained.

What is the correct probability model for the associated sampling distribution of Xn=9 ? What are the values of its mean (μ) and variance parameters (σ2)?

Find Probability [ 1 < Xn=9 £ 2.85 ]

Consider next a new random variable W = 4 Xn=9 . What is the correct normal probability
model for the sampling distribution of W? Specifically, what are the values of its mean (μ) and variance parameters (σ2)?

Comment: Why ask this? Is this homework, maybe? If so, use `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part:

$$ X_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 ... + X_9}{9} $$ where $ X_i \sim N(1, 9) $ and i.i.d.

It is clear that $X_n$ is a linear combination of $X_is$. Therefore, $X_n$ is also normally distributed.

Then lets find the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for $X_n$ (I am skipping some basic steps in derivation).

$$E(X_n) = 9*\frac{E(X_i)}{9} = E(X_i) = 1$$

$$ Var(X_n) = 9*Var(\frac{X_i}{9}) = 9*\frac{Var(X_i)}{81} = \frac{Var(X_i)}{9} $$

$$ \sigma (X_n) = \sqrt{Var(X_n)} = \frac{\sigma(X_i)}{3} = 3 $$

Now, you know the distribution of $X_n$ along with its statistics. You can compute the desired probability.

I did not understand what W equals to.